# ifelse statement with string

Tags: r, if-statement

```
double="true"

data=data.frame("var1"=c(1:10))

data$var2=ifelse(double=="true",2*data$var1,NA)
data$var2want=2*data$var1
```

I have a character that stores into double as "true" if I want to double a variable. In this example I start with var1 equal to 1:10. double="true". So I want to make var2 equals to (1:10)*2. The desired output is var2want. However, when I apply my ifelse statement I just get var2=2 for all values. I am not sure how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`double` is of length 1

```
length(double)
#[1] 1
```

whereas

```
length(data$var1)
#[1] 10
```

while using `ifelse` it returns the value which is of same length as `test` as

```
double == "true"
```

returns a vector of length 1, hence you get only one value back which is the first value of calculation

```
2*data$var1[1]
#[1] 2
```

and this value is recycled across all values.

For `ifelse` to work for all value we need to somehow make the length equal

```
ifelse(rep(double == "true", length(data$var1)), 2*data$var1, NA)
#[1]  2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18 20
```

However, if you have only one value to compare it is better to use simple `if`/`else` instead of `ifelse`

```
data$var2 <- if (double == "true") 2*data$var1 else NA
```

Comment: that is a superb explanation thank you i understand it now!